# I would like to stop immediately NSOperation in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

"A" NSOperation is to add some db recored.

1. "A" NSOperation running
2. NSOerationQueue cancelAlloperation called.
3. "A" check isCancel at first. But aleady run.
4. delete all db record on main thread;
5. "A" NSOperation add a record.
6. select all db recored on main thread. i expected record count is 0. but it is 1.

How should I fix it? I would like to wait nsoperation canceled compeletely or force stop immediately nsoperation. 5 step is not expected. I don't want to check frequently isCancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. We then used AFNetworking library.

like NSOperation, in AFNetworking we have AFHTTPRequestOperation.
it also have cancel method in this, which Manually calls  `[self.connection cancel]` causes the connection to never send another message to its delegate.

Comment: Either you can use AFNetworking or look at its internal class how it is handling the cancel operation by which you can get an idea.

Comment: I don't need to use internet. so i think its handling method may not be useful.